# I am not able to click the add a note button on using selenium and chrome webdriver could someone here help me with that

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

```
`try:
    fullLink = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/vishakha04/'
    browser.get(fullLink)
  

    browser.find_element_by_class_name('pv-s-profile-actions').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('mr1').click()
    browser.find_element_by_class_name('ml1').click()
except:
    print('error')`
```

[This is the first button connect which we are clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJBk.png)
[This are the next two buttons add a note(class mr1) and connect(class ml1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFB6U.png) 
not able to click the add a note button using find element by class

Answer (score 0):

You need to find specific paths for your elements otherwise it will click where the first path is found. Your paths are used multiple times in on the page, also your class name is incomplete and unhelpful. Partial class name aren't used like that. Try the following code

```
fullLink = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/vishakha04/'
browser.get(fullLink)

browser.find_element_by_xpaht("//span[text()='More...']").click();
time.sleep(2)

browser.find_element_by_xpaht("//button[contains(@class,'Connect with')]").click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Add a note']").click();
#or by css
browser. find_element_by_css_selector("button[aria-lable='Add a note']").click();
```